# How can I re-render a page on an express-route with an error message?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, authentication, routes

I am developing a simple website that supports a login and logout functionality based on a local JSON file with a list of users and hashed passwords. I am using express-session for my cookie to track if a user is successfully logged in or not on the server side and express as my server.

On my login page, I render the login.handlebars view. If the user successfully logs in with matching credentials the page re-routes to /private. Currently, if a user does not enter matching login credentials the page refreshes.

If a user attempted to login with incorrect credentials, I need to re-render / refresh the same page, only this time with a 401 status code, and displaying an error message on the page.

Here is what I have so far in my login route on the server side:

```
router.get("/", async (req, res) => {
    res.render("login/login")
})

router.post("/", async (req, res) => {
    // Check if user name is in users
    for(let i=0; i < users.length; i++){

        // If the user name is valid and found in the data base
        if(users[i].username === req.body.username){
            // Compare the passwords of the user to the hashedPassword that is stored
            let hashcmp = await bcrypt.compare(req.body.password, users[i].hashedPassword)

            if(hashcmp){
                // Set the cookie and authenticate the login
                console.log("Correct user name and password, setting AuthCookie")
                req.session.userId = String(users[i]._id)
                req.session.loggedin = true
                // Redirect to private
                res.redirect("/private")
                return
            }
            // If the passwords dont match --> break the loop
            else{
                break
            }
        }
    }

    // Otherwise redirect to get /login
    // TODO: Re-render page with error message and 401 status code
    res.redirect("/login")
    return
})
```

What is the best / most ideal solution to achieve this? How is this done in actual practice with the login pages if the page additionally needs to be re-rendered?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [connect-flash](https://github.com/jaredhanson/connect-flash)
. It is a Flash message middleware for Express. I advise you read a little about this.

> The flash is a special area of the session used for storing messages.
>   Messages are written to the flash and cleared after being displayed to
>   the user. The flash is typically used in combination with redirects,
>   ensuring that the message is available to the next page that is to be
>   rendered.

First, In your `app.js` file, require this module `const flash = require('connect-flash');`
Then, in the same file and before your routes definition, add this code

```
app.use(flash());

// Add errors on locals.
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  res.locals.errors = req.flash("error");
  next();
});
```

`res.locals` is an object that contains response local variables available to the next rendered view.
Next, in your controller, before `res.redirect("/login")`, add your error message in locals object.

```
// Otherwise redirect to get /login
// TODO: Re-render page with error message and 401 status code
req.flash("error", "User does not exist.");
res.redirect("/login")
```

The last you have to do is to add `errors` on your login view. I am not sure about handlebars, but in `ejs` files i use this:

```
<div>
<% errors.forEach(function (error) { %>
    <p><%= error %></p>       
<% }) %>
</div>
```

Perhaps in handlebars you can use something like this

```
<div>
  {{#each errors}}
    <p>{{this}}</p>
  {{/each}}
</div>
```

Again, you should read how `connect-flash` works and what you can do with this module. It is very useful for different kind of messages, not only error messages.

Answer (score 0):

It's simple. Just use the `res.render` to render the required page by passing in the error message

```
// Otherwise redirect to get /login
// TODO: Re-render page with error message and 401 status code
res.status(401).render("login/login", { error: "Opps!" })
return
```

In you view have a conditional:

```
<div class="error">
  {{#if error}}
    <p>{{error}}</p>
  {{/if}}
</div>
```